# Combine Cocoapods and Carthage

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods, carthage

I'm creating a Swift framework that is dependent on several other third party frameworks. Both these other frameworks support Carthage and Cocoapods.

Is there any way I can make my own framework support installing using both Carhage and Cocoapods? Or is just not achievable and should I just pick one?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can definitely make your framework available with both CocoaPods and Carthage. This is the path that I would recommend to allow your users to use whatever solution they prefer. Also note that setting a framework up to work with Carthage also makes it much easier for users who want to use your library without either of these solutions.

On a high level, for CocoaPods you'll want to create a podspec that lists your dependencies there. This way CocoaPods will manage downloading and configuring them along with resolving them against other user dependencies. See more [here](http://guides.cocoapods.org/making/making-a-cocoapod.html).

For Carthage you'll want to configure your project with framework targets for the platforms you support and add your dependencies in your Cartfile. More on that [here](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage#supporting-carthage-for-your-framework)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I must be doing something wrong with my Cocoapods file then. I have my dependencies listed using, for example, `s.dependency 'BrightFutures', '~> 1.0'`. When running `pod spec lint` it fails with: `Unable to satisfy the following requirements: - BrightFutures (~> 1.0) required by Spine (0.1)`.

Comment: Looks to me like this is because BrightFutures doesn't have a matching version. You may have to explicitly set the version to the beta versions that are currently released. (seen [here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/tree/master/Specs/BrightFutures))

Comment: Thanks! I thought I already tried that, but apparently I hadn't :).

Answer (score 6):

Combining both is actually not difficult. With my framework I have started with CocoaPods template containing `Example` and `Pod` directories. In the example project I created a new `Cocoa Touch Framework` target, made sure this target is Shared (in Product - Schemes - Managed Schemes) and dragged content of my `Pod/Classes` directory to the project (with unchecked `Copy items if needed` and added `Target Membership` only to this newly created framework).

This should be enough, Carthage should find this shared scheme and use it. Just keep in mind you have to commit changes and create a new git tag before using your framework from Carthage.